# How to plot xyz point data using deck.gl

Tags: deck.gl

Im very new to DeckGL and was wondering if I can plot regular data on it. For example I have a Datset of Points that I would like to plot. But I havent had much sucess using the Scatterplot layer (https://deck.gl/examples/scatterplot-layer/). I think DeckGL expects me to supply geoCoordinates but I want to plot XYZ plots using it. Is this possible to do? I tried to emulate the 3d point cloud example - but that really didnt work very well for me.

Comment: Did you look at the "loaders.gl" example? Is your data in .csv format?  https://loaders.gl/modules/csv/docs/api-reference/csv-loader

Comment: I did but it didnt seem to work. I ended up writing a whole different bit of code to do this for me using JSON files